# javascript object method fails to assign ajax call response

Tags: javascript, ajax, object

I've defined the following object:

```
var WealthyLaughingDuckControl = {
    initialised: false,
    users: [],
    fetchData: function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "../php/client/json.php",
            data: {
                type: "users"
            }
        }).done(function(response) {
            this.initialised = true;
            this.users = response;
        });
    },
    init: function() {
        if (!this.initialised) {
            this.fetchData();
        }
    },
    getData: function() {
        return this.users;
    }
};
```

I'm debugging this object in the browser javascript console. The state of the object is the same before and after executing `WealthyLaughingDuckControl.init()`:

```
Object {initialised: false, users: Array[0], fetchData: function, init: function, getData: function}
```

However, I'm sure that the ajax response works correctly, because when I execute the following:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "../php/client/json.php",
            data: {
                type: "users"
            }
        }).done(function(response) {
            alert(response);
        });
```

the browser alerts me with `[Object object]`. So I expect the object to have `initialised=true` and `users` set to the object response value. What is wrong in the above code?

Comment: What is `response` supposed to return a JSON?

Comment: @icanc sorry, I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the context parameter in your ajax call to your object in order to use it in the ajax callbacks.

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        context: this,
        url: "../php/client/json.php",
        data: {
            type: "users"
        }
    }).done(function(response) {
        this.initialised = true;
        this.users = response;
    });
```

> context
>   Type: PlainObject
>   This object will be made the context of all Ajax-related callbacks. By default, the context is an >object that represents the ajax settings used in the call ($.ajaxSettings merged with the settings >passed to $.ajax). For example, specifying a DOM element as the context will make that the context for >the complete callback of a request, like so:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body
}).done(function() {
  $(this).addClass("done");
});
```